# Split 1 cell into 3 and 4 cells with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

The below code splits the data from 1 cell into 3 or 4 cells from a array. The problem that I have with it is when the data doesn't fall into any of the cases sometimes it starts splitting by one of the cases and sometimes if it's below the 15 characters. Then if you run it again and finds only 6 chr it will write the 6 chr in cell 1 and then if the split was done first time and data is correct second time it runs will override and put empty cells instead. Can't work out how to solve this problem if the split was done then ignore what is selected and if it doesn't fall in any of the cases ignore cell and move to the next.

```
   Sub splitText()
       Dim wb As Workbook
       Dim Ws As Worksheet
       Set wb = ThisWorkbook
       Set Ws = ActiveSheet

       Dim srcArea As Range
       Set srcArea = Selection

       Dim dstArea As Range
       Set dstArea = Selection

       Dim results As Variant                       'array of split data
       results = SplitSourceData(srcArea)

       '--- define where the results go, based on the size that comes back
       Set dstArea = dstArea.Resize(UBound(results, 1), 4)
       dstArea = results
   End Sub

   Function SplitSourceData(srcData As Range) As Variant
       '--- starting positions for substrings
       Dim stylePos As String
       Dim fabricPos As String
       Dim colourPos As String
       Dim sizePos As String

       '--- lengths of substrings
       Dim styleLen As Long
       Dim fabricLen As Long
       Dim colourLen As Long
       Dim sizelen As Long

       '--- copy source data to memory-based array
       Dim i As Long
       Dim src As Variant
       src = srcData

       '--- set up memory-based destination array
       '    Excel does not allow resizing the first dimension of a
       '    multi-dimensional array, so we'll cheat a little and
       '    create a Range with the sized dimensions we need (in an
       '    unused area of the Worksheet), then pull that in as the
       '    2D array size we need
       Dim blankArea As Range
       Set blankArea = ActiveSheet.Range("ZZ1").Resize(UBound(src, 1), 4)
       Dim dst As Variant
       dst = blankArea

       '--- these positions and lengths seems fixed for every
       '    possible format, so no need to reset them for each loop
       stylePos = 1
       styleLen = 6

       For i = 1 To UBound(src)
           '--- decomposition formats determined by data length
           Select Case Len(src(i, 1))
           Case 15
               fabricPos = 7
               fabricLen = 5
               colourPos = 12
               colourLen = 4
               sizePos = 1
               sizelen = 0   'no size in this data
           Case 20
               fabricPos = 7
               fabricLen = 5
               colourPos = 12
               colourLen = 4
               sizePos = 19
               sizelen = 2
           Case 21
               fabricPos = 7
               fabricLen = 5
               colourPos = 12
               colourLen = 4
               sizePos = 19
               sizelen = 3
           Case 22
               fabricPos = 8
               fabricLen = 5
               colourPos = 14
               colourLen = 4
               sizePos = 21
               sizelen = 2
           Case Else
               Debug.Print "Worning! Undefined data length in row " & i & ", len=" & Len(src(i, 1))
           End Select
           dst(i, 1) = Mid(src(i, 1), stylePos, styleLen)
           dst(i, 2) = Mid(src(i, 1), fabricPos, fabricLen)
           dst(i, 3) = Mid(src(i, 1), colourPos, colourLen)
           dst(i, 4) = Mid(src(i, 1), sizePos, sizelen)
   nextDataSource:
       Next i
       SplitSourceData = dst   'return the destination array

   End Function
```

Comment: Can you show an example of what you want vs what the code produces for various cases? The question isn't really that clear.

Comment: This seems fairly simple to do. I would not do it the way you have proposed though.  Think about how you would identify the different segments manually.  In your code, you account for lengths of `{15,20,21,22}` but your examples are lengths `{15,20,24,25,28}`  I can sort of see how you are identifying `style, fabric and color`.  But I cannot figure out what, in the string, constitutes `size`.  That is why, as @Kyle writes,  examples of not only your data, but also what you expect to return from your data, would be so helpful.

Comment: There is a nice solution based on your provided sample data but I am reluctant to provide it if this is just going to turn into a 'russian doll' question; e.g. but what if..., but what if..., but what if..., but what if..., but what if..., but what if..., but what if..., but what if..., but what if..., but what if..., *ad infinitum*.

Comment: @Kyle I just updated the info to include a picture with the before and after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a Regular Expression to get the values.  I would also create a Class object to handle the data.  The properties of the class object will be the items you are looking for.  We gather all the class objects into a collection; then outputting the results is trivial.

**EDIT**:

- Regex corrected to allow for optional size parameter.
- Test added to exit macro if zero matches.
- Test added to check for just a single line to be split

I based the field definitions on your code and examples.  So if they are not all inclusive, post back with "failures".

Using a class lets the routine be more self-documenting, and also makes future modifications easier

Be sure to rename the Class module as noted in the comments

### Class Module

```
Option Explicit
'Rename this Class Module  cFabric
Private pStyle As String
Private pFabric As String
Private pColour As String
Private pSize As String

Public Property Get Style() As String
    Style = pStyle
End Property
Public Property Let Style(Value As String)
    pStyle = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Fabric() As String
    Fabric = pFabric
End Property
Public Property Let Fabric(Value As String)
    pFabric = UCase(Value)
End Property

Public Property Get Colour() As String
    Colour = pColour
End Property
Public Property Let Colour(Value As String)
    pColour = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Size() As String
    Size = pSize
End Property
Public Property Let Size(Value As String)
    pSize = Value
End Property
```

### Regular Module

```
Option Explicit
Sub Fabrics()
    'assume data is in column A
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, wsRes As Worksheet
    Dim vSrc As Variant, vRes As Variant, rRes As Range
    Dim RE As Object, MC As Object
    Const sPat As String = "^(.{6})\s*(.{5})\s*(.{4})(?:.*1/(\S+))?"
        'Group 1 = style
        'Group 2 = fabric
        'Group 3 = colour
        'Group 4 = size
    Dim colF As Collection, cF As cFabric
    Dim I As Long
    Dim S As String
    Dim V As Variant

'Set source and results worksheets and ranges
Set wsSrc = Worksheets("sheet1")
Set wsRes = Worksheets("sheet1")
    Set rRes = wsRes.Cells(1, 3)

'Read source data into array
With wsSrc
    vSrc = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
End With

'Initialize the Collection object
Set colF = New Collection

'Initialize the Regex Object
Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Global = False
    .MultiLine = True
    .Pattern = sPat

    'iterate through the list

'Test for single cell
If Not IsArray(vSrc) Then
    V = vSrc
    ReDim vSrc(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
    vSrc(1, 1) = V
End If

For I = 1 To UBound(vSrc, 1)
    S = vSrc(I, 1)
    Set cF = New cFabric
    If .test(S) = True Then
        Set MC = .Execute(S)
        With MC(0)
            cF.Style = .submatches(0)
            cF.Fabric = .submatches(1)
            cF.Colour = .submatches(2)
            cF.Size = .submatches(3)
        End With
    Else
        cF.Style = S
    End If
    colF.Add cF
Next I
End With

'create results array
'Exit if not results
If colF.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub

ReDim vRes(0 To colF.Count, 1 To 4)

'headers
vRes(0, 1) = "Style"
vRes(0, 2) = "Fabric"
vRes(0, 3) = "Colour"
vRes(0, 4) = "Size"

'Populate the rest
I = 0
For Each V In colF
    I = I + 1
    With V
        vRes(I, 1) = .Style
        vRes(I, 2) = .Fabric
        vRes(I, 3) = .Colour
        vRes(I, 4) = .Size
    End With
Next V

'Write the results
Set rRes = rRes.Resize(UBound(vRes, 1) + 1, UBound(vRes, 2))
With rRes
    .EntireColumn.Clear
    .NumberFormat = "@"
    .Value = vRes
    With .Rows(1)
        .Font.Bold = True
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    End With
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With

End Sub
```

### Regex Explanation

### ^(.{6})\s*(.{5})\s*(.{4})(?:.*1/(\S+))?

```
^(.{6})\s*(.{5})\s*(.{4})(?:.*1/(\S+))?
```

Options: Case sensitive; ^$ match at line breaks

- [Assert position at the beginning of a line](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^`
- [Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) `(.{6})`

  - [Match any single character that is NOT a line break character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) `.{6}`

    - [Exactly 6 times](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit) `{6}`
- [Match a single character that is a “whitespace character”](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\s*`

  - [Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `*`
- [Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 2](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) `(.{5})`

  - [Match any single character that is NOT a line break character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) `.{5}`

    - [Exactly 5 times](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit) `{5}`
- [Match a single character that is a “whitespace character”](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\s*`

  - [Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `*`
- [Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 3](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) `(.{4})`

  - [Match any single character that is NOT a line break character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) `.{4}`

    - [Exactly 4 times](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit) `{4}`
- [Match the regular expression below](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) `(?:.*1/(\S+))?`

  - [Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) `?`
  - [Match any single character that is NOT a line break character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) `.*`

    - [Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `*`
  - [Match the character string “1/” literally](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `1/`
  - [Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 4](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) `(\S+)`

    - [Match a single character that is NOT a “whitespace character”](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\S+`

      - [Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+`

Created with [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/)

Comment: This is very interesting I've tested it and works but it's not as flexible as i hoped it will be. What i mean by that i need this to work on all sheets of the workbook. Don't need the headers as the user will paste the data in the style column the will proceed with the split. The split should be done from the user selection as it will be maybe 10 rows to split maybe less each time. I know we should not use `selection` but i don't know any other way to get the row data that need splitting except if the user selects the data and press button to split also column A need to be override with Style.

Comment: @QuickSilver Just change the lines that determine the selection of the Source data, and where the results go, to use whatever algorithm seems appropriate for your real requirements.

Comment: Just finished editing the code and it's working perfectly but there 2 bugs that i notice after trying all sort of data. One bug has to do with the fact that it doesn't have a size so that one is not splitting and second one is after splitting if run again on the split data gives a run time error 9 subscript out of range on line `ReDim vRes(1 To colF.Count, 1 To 4)` which i can do a error handler to handle this scenario but i can't work out how to solve the first one as what you did is to advanced for me at the moment thank you for your help in this matter.

Comment: Please provide actual examples of what is not working.  PS  I hate error handlers and would rather avoid them if possible.

Comment: Rosendelf i have this data: **363998W0ZR18171**,
363998W0ZR18171 1/35.5,
363998W0ZR18171  1/35.5c,
363998W0ZR18171- 1/56.5 The one in bold is the problematic one because it doesn't have a size so basically it's not falling into one of the criteria i think.

Comment: Regarding the error handler i do not know a way to avoid the `ReDim vRes(1 To colF.Count, 1 To 4)` if the data was already processed and by mistake it runs again. Had the same issue with the original code after splitting the data and run again it was overriding it at some point.

Comment: Rosenfield The other thing that i notice with my original code is the same with this one if there is only 1 cell selected it throws a run time error 13 type mismatch at line `For I = 1 To UBound(vSrc, 1)` that have no idea how to fix if you can point me in the right direction will be much appreciated.

Comment: @QuickSilver So far as the non-split with missing size, I overlooked that.  But the fix is a simple change in the regex to make the size optional.  So far as the re-running problem, all we need to do is test that there are entries in ColF before processing the results. I will make those changes in the code

Comment: @QuickSilver The type mismatch with a single cell selected is due to the fact that a single cell does not create an array on our vSrc = line.  The fix is to test for whether vSrc is an array; if it is not, then we alter it.  See the edited code for the fix.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141719/discussion-between-quicksilver-and-ron-rosenfeld).

Comment: Ronsenfeld This is amazing it works perfectly but there is one thing i don't understand where does the #N/A coming from I can't see it anywhere in the code? Will it be possible to join me in the chat?

Comment: @Quicksilver won't be able to until this evening. Going out now.

Comment: Ronsenfeld Do you know if it will be possible for example if there is a blank row between the data to preserve the same when it starts writing the result as now it writes the result in the next empty row and kind of moves the split data one row up? Maybe if you have time some day to discuss more about this so i can understand how it work it will be very much appreciated. But this is amazing stuff would never though something like this is even possible. Maybe it's good that moves data up need to test it more to see how it works. Will replay back with the results of this amazing code. Thank you!

Comment: @QuickSilver A number of approaches.  If you are not overwriting data (and I advise against that for debugging and also audit reasons), you could just save a blank cF object in the collection (or you could set `cF.Style = S` if the regex test fails).  If you must overwrite, then the programming will be more complicated.  If you only want to return blanks, and not the Non Matches, you could do that.  First you have to decide what you want to do, exactly.

Comment: basically what happens is that if there is a blank row in between the data then the split data will write on that blank row it will not keep it empty as the original format. Don't want to override any data because I'll lose track of it at some point. Like to keep everything simple.

Comment: As I wrote, you just add a "blank" cF object.  I edited to just return the string if the regex.test fails.  And if the string is a blank, that is what will be returned.  So far as NA is concerned, I don't see how that could be coming from the macro.  It is likely something in your worksheet.

Comment: I tried to add a blank cF object but not sure i did it properly `Public Property Get BlankCell() As String
    BlankCell = pBlank
End Property
Public Property Let BlankCell(Value As String)
    pBlank = Value
End Property` is this the correct  way?

Comment: No.  Your method tries to add a property to the `cF` object. (Note that you are using the `Property` keyword).  You don't need to do anything -- reread my last comment.  Run the revised macro and it should include the blank lines.

Comment: it works amazing. I've declared this as range to be able to work with this from the user selection. `Dim wsSrc As Range, wsRes As Range
    Dim vSrc As Variant, vRes As Variant, rRes As Range` and `Set wsSrc = Selection
Set wsRes = Selection
    Set rRes = wsRes.Cells(1, 1)` and `vSrc = Selection` also at the end i deleted the headers and fromatting and `ReDim vRes(1 To colF.Count, 1 To 4)` to override the source cell. One bug that is still there when you split data and you run it again will override existing data is there a way if the count is 6 in the source cell ignore?

Comment: @QuickSilver I don't really understand what you've done or why.  I don't understand the logic of why you declared variables designed to refer to particular worksheets as referring to ranges.  And I would strongly recommend that you NOT overwrite the original data (for audit purposes).  And yes, if you are going to retain blanks, and NOT overwrite previously split data, you will also need to decide how you want to handle mal-formed data.   I suggest you pose a new question with these problems, including the code as you have modified it, and clear examples demonstrating your issues.

Comment: For some reason it was giving me a run time error 13 type mismatch if i would have left it as original. Also i needed to work off the user selection and on 4 worksheets that i need to run on and don't know another way to do it. Will post another question with the modifications that i did and the errors or do you what to go on the chat i think this will be a lot quicker to clarify there the issue.

Comment: You would be better served to find and correct the cause of the error as opposed to changing the logic of the algorithm.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142341/discussion-between-quicksilver-and-ron-rosenfeld).

Comment: I cannot. I am not at my computer.

Comment: Ok you are right i just found the problem from the initial code everything that was in the source data was copied on a separate sheet called sheet1 that's why i was getting that error. I've replace the below code to suit my needs. `Dim wsSrc As Workbook, wsRes As Workbook` and `Set wsSrc = ActiveWorkbook
Set wsRes = ActiveWorkbook` and ` Set rRes = wsRes.Application.Selection vSrc = Application.Selection` with this changes it works on all `activeworkbooks` from user selection exactly how i need it to work as this needs to work on multiple workbooks. Is this a better approach ?

Comment: I don't think so. As originally written, the worksheets to which wsSrc & wsRes were referring to would have been relative to the active workbook.

Comment: You could explicitly make them all that way by defining a WB variable equal to the active workbook I supposed,

Comment: There is one bug that in it that after the first splitting of the cell is done and by mistake you run it again will override the data. [This is the link to my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43560650/how-to-solve-this-override-data-regex-vba)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you can just normalize the data by removing the extra parts and [split by fixed widths](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/office/ff193593):

```
Dim r As Range
Set r = Cells.CurrentRegion

r.Replace " - 1/", ""
r.Replace " 1/", ""
r.Replace " ", ""

r.TextToColumns r, xlFixedWidth, FieldInfo:=[{0,1;6,1;11,1;15,1}]
r.CurrentRegion.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
```

Comment: This is an amazing approach it's simple yet very effective thank you. There is one problem though after extensive testing i discovered that is in between the 4 lines that needs splitting there is one that doesn't needs splitting but to be quick with the data entry you just select everything then it will override the data that doesn't need anything done to it that's the only problem i discovered with this method. Need something that will do the job as this will be used by other and even if i explain it will happen in the end to do that and override data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no `excel-vba` expert, but it sure looks to me like in the `case else` situation, it still loads your destination cells with values, based on whatever *Pos* and *Len* values were left over from the previous row.  That is, when you hit a row with an undefined length, it will print your warning (which is misspelled, btw), and then continue on and execute the `dst(1, n) =` lines.  At that point, whatever was in StylePos, StyleLen, etc. from the previous iteration will be used.

There are at least two ways to solve this.  First, you can put `goto nextDataSource` inside the `Case Else` block.  That will skip the loading of *dst*.

The other option is to add something like `errFlag = 1` to the `Case Else` and then put a test around the load of *dst*:

```
if (errFlag = 0) then
   dst(i, 1) = Mid...
End if
```

Don't forget, of course, to set errFlag to 0 right before the `Select Case` statement.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Just updated the post to include a picture with the before and after result.

Answer (score 0):

> <sup>I wrote this while waiting for an answer to a comment. [Ron Rosenfeld](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2872922/ron-rosenfeld)'s recent regex-based answer is much  more thorough than this but I'm posting it in case you want some direction in creating a function rather than a sub procedure. The regex .Pattern used here was based on your original sample data and will not work on your newer sample data (which I have no intention of retyping in any event)</sup>

Use a User Defined Function based on Regular Expression text parsing to split off the first set of lower case letters. After that, anything that is located as another placeholder to split on is only a single character.

```
Option Explicit

Function explodePieces(str As String, Optional ndx As Long = 1)
    Dim i As Long, result As Variant
    Static cmat As Object, regex As Object

    ReDim result(1 To 4)
    result(1) = str
    If regex Is Nothing Then
        Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        With regex
            .Global = False
            .MultiLine = False
            .IgnoreCase = False
        End With
    Else
        Set cmat = Nothing
    End If

    With regex
        .Pattern = "[a-z]{3}"
        If regex.Test(str) Then
            Set cmat = .Execute(str)
            result(1) = Split(str, cmat.Item(cmat.Count - 1))(0)
            result(2) = cmat.Item(cmat.Count - 1)
            Select Case ndx
                Case 1, 2
                    'nothing more to do
                Case 3, 4
                    result(3) = Split(str, cmat.Item(cmat.Count - 1))(1)
                    i = InStrRev(result(3), Chr(47))
                    If CBool(i) Then
                        i = InStrRev(result(3), Chr(32), i)
                        result(4) = Mid(result(3), i)
                        result(3) = Trim(Replace(result(3), result(4), vbNullString))

                    End If
            End Select
            explodePieces = Replace(Replace(result(ndx), Chr(32), vbNullString), Chr(45), vbNullString)
        End If
    End With

End Function
```

[image]

Comment: This is a interesting approach the only thing with this function is that I will require to have the raw data in the table but i need to override the source cell with the 6 digits and then move to second column so basically the A column will be as in the above example in the B column.