# How to stop second run of the code to prevent override data regex vba?

Tags: regex, vba, excel

The below code will split 1 cell into 3 or 4 column based on a pattern of 6chr,5chr,4chr,5+chr. The below also needs to be available on all open workbooks and work from the user selection.

*How to fix a bug that after the first splitting of the cell is done and by mistake you run it again will override the data?*

**Class Module**

```
Option Explicit
'Rename this Class Module  cFabric
Private pStyle As String
Private pFabric As String
Private pColour As String
Private pSize As String

Public Property Get Style() As String
    Style = pStyle
End Property
Public Property Let Style(Value As String)
    pStyle = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Fabric() As String
    Fabric = pFabric
End Property
Public Property Let Fabric(Value As String)
    pFabric = UCase(Value)
End Property

Public Property Get Colour() As String
    Colour = pColour
End Property
Public Property Let Colour(Value As String)
    pColour = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Size() As String
    Size = pSize
End Property
Public Property Let Size(Value As String)
    pSize = Value
End Property
```

**Regular Module**

```
Option Explicit
Sub Fabrics()

    Dim wsSrc As Workbook, wsRes As Workbook
    Dim vSrc As Variant, vRes As Variant, rRes As Range
    Dim RE As Object, MC As Object

    Const sPat As String = "^(.{6})\s*(.{5})\s*(.{4})(?:.*1/(\S+))?"
        'Group 1 = style
        'Group 2 = fabric
        'Group 3 = colour
        'Group 4 = size
    Dim colF As Collection, cF As cFabric
    Dim I As Long
    Dim S As String
    Dim V As Variant

'Set source and results worksheets and ranges
Set wsSrc = ActiveWorkbook
Set wsRes = ActiveWorkbook
    Set rRes = wsRes.Application.Selection

'Read source data into array
vSrc = Application.Selection

'Initialize the Collection object
Set colF = New Collection

'Initialize the Regex Object
Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Global = False
    .MultiLine = True
    .Pattern = sPat

'Test for single cell
If Not IsArray(vSrc) Then
    V = vSrc
    ReDim vSrc(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
    vSrc(1, 1) = V
End If

    'iterate through the list
For I = 1 To UBound(vSrc, 1)
    S = vSrc(I, 1)
    Set cF = New cFabric
    If .test(S) = True Then
        Set MC = .Execute(S)
        With MC(0)
            cF.Style = .submatches(0)
            cF.Fabric = .submatches(1)
            cF.Colour = .submatches(2)
            cF.Size = .submatches(3)
        End With
    Else
        cF.Style = S
    End If
    colF.Add cF
Next I
End With

'create results array
'Exit if no results
If colF.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub

ReDim vRes(1 To colF.Count, 1 To 4)

'Populate the rest
I = 0
For Each V In colF
    I = I + 1
    With V
        vRes(I, 1) = .Style
        vRes(I, 2) = .Fabric
        vRes(I, 3) = .Colour
        vRes(I, 4) = .Size
    End With
Next V

'Write the results
Set rRes = rRes.Resize(UBound(vRes, 1), UBound(vRes, 2))
    rRes.Value = vRes

End Sub
```

*Credits for the above goes to @Ron Rosenfeld for the project!*

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: Try removing the final "?" from the regex pattern.

Comment: @RichHolton Tried removing the "?" but still didn't work.

Comment: @RobinMackenzie How to fix the code in order not to override data if run more then 1 time?

Comment: Change the address of `rRes` - the code you posted does what you want just you don't want to the second run to change the first. You need to update the question otherwise it will be closed I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to tell if the entry has been previously split is as follows

- If the regex.test fails, then

  - If the results line passes, then the item has been previously split
  - if not, then it is a blank, or a malformed entry

Note that a lot of this could be avoided if you were not overwriting your original data.  I would recommend against overwriting your data both for audit and debugging purposes, but the below should help in case you cannot change that.

You just need to make some small changes in the logic where we checked for the malformed entry originally.  As well as reading in the "possible" results array into vSrc so that we have the potentially split data to compare:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Fabrics()
    'assume data is in column A
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, wsRes As Worksheet
    Dim vSrc As Variant, vRes As Variant, rRes As Range
    Dim RE As Object, MC As Object
    Const sPat As String = "^(.{6})\s*(.{5})\s*(.{4})(?:.*1/(\S+))?"
        'Group 1 = style
        'Group 2 = fabric
        'Group 3 = colour
        'Group 4 = size
    Dim colF As Collection, cF As cFabric
    Dim I As Long
    Dim S As String
    Dim V As Variant

'Set source and results worksheets and ranges
Set wsSrc = ActiveSheet
Set wsRes = ActiveSheet
    Set rRes = Selection

'Read source data into array
vSrc = Selection.Resize(columnsize:=4)

'Initialize the Collection object
Set colF = New Collection

'Initialize the Regex Object
Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Global = False
    .MultiLine = True
    .Pattern = sPat

    'iterate through the list

'Test for single cell
If Not IsArray(vSrc) Then
    V = vSrc
    ReDim vSrc(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
    vSrc(1, 1) = V
End If

For I = 1 To UBound(vSrc, 1)
    S = vSrc(I, 1)
    Set cF = New cFabric
    If .test(S) = True Then
        Set MC = .Execute(S)
        With MC(0)
            cF.Style = .submatches(0)
            cF.Fabric = .submatches(1)
            cF.Colour = .submatches(2)
            cF.Size = .submatches(3)
        End With

    ElseIf .test(vSrc(I, 1) & vSrc(I, 2) & vSrc(I, 3)) = False Then
        cF.Style = S
    Else
        cF.Style = vSrc(I, 1)
        cF.Fabric = vSrc(I, 2)
        cF.Colour = vSrc(I, 3)
        cF.Size = vSrc(I, 4)
    End If
    colF.Add cF
Next I
End With

'create results array
'Exit if not results
If colF.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub

ReDim vRes(1 To colF.Count, 1 To 4)

'Populate
I = 0
For Each V In colF
    I = I + 1
    With V
        vRes(I, 1) = .Style
        vRes(I, 2) = .Fabric
        vRes(I, 3) = .Colour
        vRes(I, 4) = .Size
    End With
Next V

'Write the results
Set rRes = rRes.Resize(UBound(vRes, 1), UBound(vRes, 2))
With rRes
    .Clear
    .NumberFormat = "@"
    .Value = vRes
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Now everything is working as it should. Thank you very much for your help also i would like to point out that the file will be only for internal use of tracking and backtracking is not meant for audit as all the data is pasted from emails into the excel file. I have 2 questions for you: 1. will you use the same method to reconstruct the string without the size? 2. Is there a way from excel to import/automate  the data from outlook without having to manually copy/paste? The data will be from emails and the format is the one we are trying to split.

Comment: @QuickSilver 1. I don't understand the question. 2. Yes

Comment: What i meant with question 1 is that from the split data that is now in 3 cells to reconstruct it back into styleFabricColour? example 341416 sca06 1000 all this is now in 3 cells and in the 4th cell to be 341416sca061000 will you use the same method? Or take a different approach? Regarding question 2 so you are telling me that it is possible to transfer data from outlook to excel to specific cells and from the email extract only the info that you are interested in and put it in excel? Can you point me in the right direction regarding this? Any materials to read, learn and dev?

Comment: @QuickSilver  There are many ways to do that.  And how I would do it might be different from how you would do it. Concatenation; using the object; etc.  Why not just get it from the original source.  Or, as I have suggested many times, do not overwrite the original.  For the email issue, I suggest an internet search.  There are plenty of examples for reading emails using VBA.

Comment: Many thanks for your help and i will definitely have a look into the data transfer between Outlook and Excel. As for keeping it it's just too much info on one spreadsheet and at the end of the day it's the same info it's just needed in different formats to be able to generate pictures search for specific things see trends of items. There some files that uses the split version of it and other file uses the merged version depending on what you want to do with it that's why needed both and a way to do it quickly. Again many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Disregarding the previous regex/class method,

[image]

```
Option Explicit

Sub Fabrics_part_Deux()
    Dim a As Long, b As Long

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
        With .Range(.Cells(1, "A"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 3))
            With .Columns("B")
                .Offset(1, 0).Replace what:=Chr(32), replacement:=vbNullString, lookat:=xlPart
            End With
            .AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:="<>"
            .AutoFilter field:=3, Criteria1:=""
            With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Offset(1, 1)
                If CBool(Application.Subtotal(103, .Cells)) Then
                    With .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                        For a = 1 To .Areas.Count
                            With .Areas(a).Cells
                                .TextToColumns Destination:=.Cells(1), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
                                    FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(6, 1), Array(11, 1), Array(15, 2))
                                For b = 1 To .Rows.Count
                                    .Cells(b, 2) = UCase$(.Cells(b, 2).Value2)
                                    If CBool(InStr(1, .Cells(b, 4).Value2, Chr(47), vbBinaryCompare)) Then
                                        .Cells(b, 4) = Trim(Split(.Cells(b, 4), Chr(47))(1))
                                    End If
                                Next b
                            End With
                        Next a
                    End With
                End If
            End With
        End With
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: I've tried similar approach to yours but there is a flow in the above code. What happens if the string is changed or is just a little bit different extra space or other character that should normally not be there then the `TextToColumn` array will not be able to handle the different scenario you will then need to go in the code and change the array to include that possibility am i right ?

Comment: That wasn't the question here. The question here was about '*6chr,5chr,4chr,5+chr*'. If one remembered your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43324949/split-1-cell-into-3-and-4-cells-with-vba) then they might accommodate for the lack of a fourth element or they might have left it to you to check for the existence of a `/` character before the second TextToColumns.

Answer (score 0):

In your code to output to the spreadsheet, you need to check for empty strings

```
I = 0
For Each V In colF
    I = I + 1
    With V
        vRes(I, 1) = .Style
        If len(.Fabric) > 0 then
            vRes(I, 2) = .Fabric
            vRes(I, 3) = .Colour
            vRes(I, 4) = .Size
        End If
    End With
Next V
```

Comment: I've tried this earlier on and didn't work for me but tried it now again just in case i did something wrong but still not working. If i try second time to run it will override the data.

Comment: I just corrected my error. Note that the If statement should be looking at vRes(I,2), not vRes(I,1).

Comment: @Rick Holton The way it is now it's skipping the natural order of splitting the data and jumps and writes only the first 6 chr so still now working.

Comment: I am sorry. I keep making errors that I shouldn't. The If statement should be looking at .Fabric, not any of the vRes values. No, that still won't work. Hold on while I take a little more time to get this right.

Comment: @Rick Holton Same result as before it's not stopping the override.